# Where is the pager data in the Views object

Tags: views

I am trying to alter the number of items per page in a View, programmatically. When I display the Views object returned in hook_views_pre_execute, I see fields for in $view->query for items per page, etc., but despite the view initially having a setting of Display a specified number of items: 6, it appears nowhere in the object, that I can find.

Comment: There are two options. One, it's in `$view->query`. Second - it's simply not there at all, query gets all items and pagination happens later. Inspect query and you will be able to tell yourself. Don't forget to post self-answer once you'll find out!

Comment: I don't think those options cover things properly. I have checked the contents of $views->query also in the post_execute, pre_render and post_render hooks. In all cases the paging values are null. At SOME point, views has to have that information available in order to provide the correct number of items, so where is it?

Comment: Any solutions for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hook_views_pre_execute (hook_views_pre_build is too early), the pager data, in general, can be found at

```
$view->pager
```

and the specific piece of data I asked about can be found at

```
$view->pager->options['items_per_page']
```